# Why doesn't gcloud auth activate-service-account work on Windows?

Tags: windows, gcloud

I have a Google Cloud service account token, freshly downloaded. I'd like to activate it on Windows, Mac, and Linux as part of a CI pipeline. To do so, I do:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=./token.json
```

This works great on Linux and Mac. On Winddows, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Could not read json file C:\Users\appveyor\token.json: No JSON object could be decoded
```

The error happens no matter if I invoke `gcloud` from PowerShell or `gcloud.cmd` from cmd.exe. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out it was a character encoding problem. I was previously getting the string into AppVeyor using

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($env:GCLOUD_TOKEN)) | Out-File .\token.json
```

which was writing the file as UTF-16LE. gcloud's bundled Python didn't care for that. My next attempt utilized `Set-Content -Encoding utf8 .\token.json`, but that writes UTF-8 with a BOM, which gcloud still can't handle. Finally got it working with the following:

```
$content = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($env:GCLOUD_TOKEN)) ; $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False ; [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines('token.json', $content, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```